# Mount Azure datalake storage folder as a folder in linux ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure

I want to mount an Azure Datalake Folder as a Ubuntu folder. The [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/storage/blobs/storage-how-to-mount-container-linux) shows how to create 'system managed entities' to connect a Linux machine to ADLS, however, it shows 'REST'ful way of connecting to the folder, which is not I need. We have [blobfuse](https://docs.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/storage/blobs/storage-how-to-mount-container-linux) way of connecting Azure Storage Blob to Linux. I am looking for something similar or Azure native way to MOUNT my ADLS folder inside my Ubuntu machine.

Something like:
sudo mount -t cifs //.azuredatalakestore.net/bulk_data /home/manju/mnt --verbose  -o vers=3.0,username=xtomseursvsisldpadls,password=,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777

Answer (score 2):

goofys supports mounting azure datalake: https://github.com/kahing/goofys/blob/master/README-azure.md#azure-blob-storage

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say if you're using ADLS v1 or v2.
ADLS v2 is accessible via the standard blob api, so if you're using v2 you should be able to use blobfuse.  See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-multi-protocol-access

Comment: I am using ADLS Gen1